# Scala mapPartition collect on partition do nothing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, rdd

I'm trying to move data from rdd to postgres table, using:

```
def copyIn(reader: java.io.Reader, columnStmt: String = "") = {
        //connect to postgres database on the localhost
        val driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        var connection:Connection = null
        Class.forName(driver)
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection()

        try {
            connection.unwrap(classOf[PGConnection]).getCopyAPI.copyIn(s"COPY my_table ($columnStmt) FROM STDIN WITH CSV", reader)
        } catch {
            case se: SQLException => println(se.getMessage)
            case t: Throwable => println(t.getMessage)
        } finally {
            connection.close()
        }
    }

myRdd.mapPartitions(iter => {
        val sb = new StringBuilder()

        var n_iter = iter.map(row => {
            val mapRequest = Utils.getMyRowMap(myMap, row)
            sb.append(mapRequest.values.mkString(", ")).append("\n")
        })

        copyIn(new StringReader(sb.toString), geoSelectMap.keySet.mkString(", "))
        sb.clear
        n_iter
    }).collect
```

The script keep getting in to the CopyIn function with no data to insert in. I think it maybe because iter.map just map the partition and do not perform collect? I try to collect te whole myRdd object and still didnt get data in copyIn function.

How can I iterate over an rdd and get the StringBuilder appended and why the snippet above doesn't work?
Anybody have a clue?

Comment: You are returning the same object as in the input of the map. (Iter)

Comment: @eliasah - see my edit- I thought it would solve it, but still no data in copyIn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iter` is an [`Iterator`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html). So `iter.map` creates a new `Iterator`, but you don't actually iterate it and it does nothing. You probably want `foreach` instead. Except then `iter` will be empty by the time you return it and the result of `collect` will be an empty RDD.

The actual method you want is `foreachPartition`:

```
myRdd.foreachPartition(iter => {
        val sb = new StringBuilder()

        iter.foreach(row => {
            val mapRequest = Utils.getMyRowMap(myMap, row)
            sb.append(mapRequest.values.mkString(", ")).append("\n")
        })

        copyIn(new StringReader(sb.toString), geoSelectMap.keySet.mkString(", "))
        sb.clear
    })
```

and then `myRdd.collect` if you want to collect it as well. ([Persist](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) `myRdd` if you want to use it twice without recalculating it.)